# AutoHotKey: catching & manipulating windows without human interaction

Tags: automation, window, autohotkey

Something sounding very basic has taken a lot of time: how can an ***AutoHotKey*** script be programmed to wait for a specific window and then accept it, `Send {enter}`, to close it down? In this case it’s an annoying settings confirmation dialogue which comes up every time certain file types are opened for a programme. A minor complication is also that the windows title changes every time, while its `ahn_class` is shared with the mother programme – things which i’ve tried to tackle by catching the window by its pixel size instead:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class SALFRAME
    ~LButton::
    WinGetActiveStats, , width, , ,
    if (width = "681") {
        Send {enter}
    }
return
```

This works, but forces to click somewhere on the dialogue when it comes up, which is faster then before, but still not really automated. I also tried with `WinWaitActive` among other things, but it doesn’t seem to catch the window (at some point some of the scripts i’ve tried to write actually killed the window when the script was executed, but only once, without touching subsequent windows coming after the script first ran). What is the correct way to wait for and terminate certain windows without human input with ***AutoHotKey***?

Comment: WinWaitActive is the best way to go. You only find a window that property that WinWaitActive accepts and remains the same for all such windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, Send_Enter_to_specific_window, 50
return

    Send_Enter_to_specific_window:
IfWinActive ahk_class SALFRAME
{
    WinGetPos,,, width,, A
    if (width = "681")
         Send {enter}
}
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm#Examples

Comment: Just notice the last **`_`** in `Send_Enter_to_specific_window`. Thank you! What does it mean that the `Period` is 50 ms?

Comment: Corrected, thanks! The script checks every 50 ms whether the specific window exists and is active.

Comment: Right, if omitted, default is 250 ms.